# How can I implement a from_dict function with enums in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, enums

Actually having following code in python:

```
class Constants(Enum):
  ID = "identifying"
  NAME = "naming"
  OWNER = "owning"
  INFOS = "information"
  TYPE = "type"
 

class MyClass:
  def __init__(self, id_, name_, owner_, infos_, type_):
    self.id_ = id_
    self.name_ = name_
    self.owner_ = owner_
    self.infos_ = infos_ # array
    self.type_ = type_

  @classmethod
  def from_my_dict(cls, my_dict):
    # looks very extensive...
    return cls(my_dict[Constants.ID.value], my_dict[Constants.NAME.value], 
               my_dict[Constants.OWNER.value], my_dict[Constants.INFO.value],
               my_dict[Constants.TYPE.value])



  # should return self.{variableName}
  # get_variable(Constant.ID) -> return self.id
  # get_variable(Constant.INFO) -> return self.info

  def get_variable(constant):
    ...
    ???
    ...
```

whereas in my main section I want to use that. So it looks like the following:

```
...

# dictionary with keys of enum-values
# filled with: my_dict[Constants.ID] = "example", ...
my_dict = {"identifying": "example", "naming": "example", "owning": "example", "information": "example", "type": "example"}

my_object = MyClass.from_my_dict(my_dict)

value = MyClass.get_variable(Constants.TYPE)
print(value) # prints "example"
```

Now the problem with my code is that:

- it looks very extensive by now already - as it is planned to insert a few more variables to that class
- values of Enum **have to** be like here (because those are the json-keys)
- is there a neat/easy way to implement the `get_variable(constant)` function?

I am looking forward for any hints, examples and solutions to my problem. Thank you!

Comment: the design is overcomplicated making the `MyClass` doubtfully dependent  on `Constants`

Comment: You need a mapping from `Constants` to the attribute names used by your dict. You might consider just using a single `dict` attribute whose keys are also values from `Constants`, instead of making up new attribute names.

Comment: By the way, use `operator.itemgetter` to simplify `from_dict`. You can use that to define a single callable that takes a dict and returns a tuple of values corresponding to the keys passed to `itemgetter`.

Comment: @chepner couldn't follow that one exactly... but I could follow your previous answer, that disappeared with the ``itemgetter``... - just one more question to the ``get_variable(constant)``. If I ``return operator.attrgetter(constant.value)`` with e.g. ``constant = Constant.NAME`` then I get ``operator.attrgetter('naming')`` back...

Comment: Yeah, I conflated `get_variable` with simply getting a value from an `Enum` member, rather than using it to index an instance of `MyClass`. I deleted the answer because I didn't address `get_variable,` which I thought was the main point of your answer. I think the real solution here is not introducing another set of attribute names that are independent of `Constants`. Do something like `def __init__(self, id, ...): self.d = {Constants.ID.value: id, ...}`.

Comment: but then it is not possible any longer to 'simply' access to those values any longer, or? - so for example simply calling ``my_object.id``